# Check File Links in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm generating a file to be imported on my site every week with some product data that's frequently updated. Everything works except for where I generate image paths to feed the server. The images are all organized so that if you know a product name and manufacturer, you can find the image. An ABC-123's image is images/ABC/123.png

Not every product has an image though, so I'd like to test the image links and swap them out for a product logo in case the image isn't there.

Code I've tried:

```
df['images']="filepath/" + df['brand'] + "/" + df['product']
if(~os.path.isfile(df['images'].values):
    df['images']="filepath/" + df['brand'] + "logo.png"
```

And that errors out with: ValueError: stat: embedded null character in path

Doing:

```
print(os.path.isfile(df['image'][1]))
```

Works, I get a true/false as expected. So it's something to do with performing the operating on the whole data frame, which is a bit weird because as I understand it, I'm not supposed to iterate through a dataframe and then make changes to it.

Comment: You should modify your `if` with a `np.where` or an `apply`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function from pandas package to process whole DataFrame by applying inline function to each row of your DataFrame.

```
df['images'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['images'] if os.path.isfile(x['images']) else 'filepath/' + x['brand'] + '/' + 'logo.png', axis=1)
```

Comment: I think that might just do it! I had forgotten there was the .apply thing.